# How to remove year from any existing date in Magento

Tags: php, magento, cakephp, magento-1.7, cakephp-2.1

PHP Core Date 0000-06-22 can't be added as date in Magento and CakePHP

it accepts date > than 1971

so i want to replace year into '1971'

how ? Any solution ?

Comment: have you tried strtr(); ?

Comment: how can i use strtr() for replacing year ?
i couldn't get you .

Comment: `echo strtr("0000-06-22", "0000", "1971");` This should replace the 0000 with your year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str_replace('0000', '1971', '0000-06-22');
```